# How to get a variable replaced with a field name in a LINQ?

Tags: asp.net, linq

```
string companyName="ABC";
var query = from q in context.Company where q.CompanyName == companyName select q;
```

Is there any way to replace the `q.CompanyName` part of the query with a string variable
so that the field used for filtering be a parametric?

I tried

```
string str1 = "companySize";
string str2 = "q." + str1; 
string companySize = "Mid";
var query = from q in context.Company where str2 == companySize select q;
```

Didn't work.
Been trying to let the user choose the columns for the query.

Comment: Google for *Dynamic LINQ*

Comment: Already done. No help so far!

Comment: @Jude Its is the [first hit on google](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read more about both below option at : [**Dynamic query with Linq**](http://pranayamr.blogspot.no/2011/04/dynamic-query-with-linq.html)

you can use one of this

1. Use Dynamic LINQ library

   Example for the the blog below

   ```
   string strWhere = string.Empty;
   string strOrderBy = string.Empty;

   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAddress.Text))
       strWhere = "Address.StartsWith(\"" + txtAddress.Text + "\")"; 
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmpId.Text))
   {
       if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strWhere ))
           strWhere = " And ";
       strWhere = "Id = " + txtEmpId.Text;
   }
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDesc.Text))
   {
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strWhere))
           strWhere = " And ";
       strWhere = "Desc.StartsWith(\"" + txtDesc.Text + "\")";
   }
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Text))
   {
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strWhere))
           strWhere = " And ";
       strWhere = "Name.StartsWith(\"" + txtName.Text + "\")";
   }

   EmployeeDataContext edb = new EmployeeDataContext();
   var emp = edb.Employees.Where(strWhere);
   ```
2. Predicate Builder

EXample

```
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<employee>();

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAddress.Text))
        predicate = predicate.And(e1 => e1.Address.Contains(txtAddress.Text));
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmpId.Text))
        predicate = predicate.And(e1 => e1.Id == Convert.ToInt32(txtEmpId.Text));
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDesc.Text))
        predicate = predicate.And(e1 => e1.Desc.Contains(txtDesc.Text));
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Text))
        predicate = predicate.And(e1 => e1.Name.Contains(txtName.Text));

    EmployeeDataContext edb= new EmployeeDataContext();
    var emp = edb.Employees.Where(predicate);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use libraries like dynamicLINQ, you can just create the Expression Tree by yourself:

```
string str1 = "companySize";
string str2 = "q." + str1; 
string companySize = "Mid";

var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string));
var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<Company, bool>>(
              Expression.Equal(
                  Expression.Property(param, str1),
                  Expression.Constant(companySize)),
              param);

var query = context.Company.Where(exp);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this is with built in libraries (and PropertyDescriptor type).

```
using System.ComponentModel;

void Main()
{
   Test test = new Test();
   test.CompanyName = "ABC";

   object z = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(test).OfType<PropertyDescriptor>()
                  .Where(x => x.Name == "CompanyName").Select(x => x.GetValue(test)).FirstOrDefault();

   Console.WriteLine(z.ToString());
}

public class Test
{
   public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```